# TextView class error.

Tags: android, textview

I have the following error in MainActivity.java:

> "Cannot resolve symbol mainTextView."

why is the error mainTextView occurring? please.

I am new to developing android & simply following a tutorial

```
@Override

     public void onClick(View view) {
         // Test the Button
         mainTextView.setText("Button pressed!");

     }
```

inside of.....

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.android.omgandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView mainTextView;
        mainTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
        mainTextView.setText("Set in Java");
        Button mainButton;
        mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Test the Button
        mainTextView.setText("Button pressed!");

    }
}
```

the activitymain.xml reads

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/main_textview" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your `TextView mainTextView` public, because else it is not accessable from the onClick method - it is defined only in the onCreate method. So put `public TextView mainTextView;` out of the methods (just before this lines `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`) and remove `TextView mainTextView;` from the onCreate method

Comment: Thanks, very rookie mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
TextView mainTextView;
```

after this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Like follwing

```
public class MainActivity extends....
TextView mainTextView;
```

If you declare it inside the `onCreate`, you can use only inside of it. If you want to use it in other methods, you have make the object public, like well explained in the @Gabriella answer

Comment: You can't do this! It should be INSIDE the Activity class, but before all of the methods

Comment: merci, very trivial rookie mistake.